# Printing row number of selected row in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I am building a single page application using Angular 8. I have a table who's values are hard coded for now in the .ts file as below :

```
 displayedColumns = ['select', 'position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(ELEMENT_DATA);
  selection = new SelectionModel<Element>(true, []);



const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
];
```

I have written a function in the .ts file to output the selected row as below :

```
selectedRow() {

        const rowNumber = this.selection.selected;
        console.log("row number that is selected : " + rowNumber);
    }
```

The html file then implements the code to display this table along with checkboxes as below :

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Checkbox Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                      [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                      [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
        </mat-checkbox>
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); selectedRow()"
                      (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                      [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
        </mat-checkbox>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
             (click)="selection.toggle(row)">
    </mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

Now a table of rows is displayed in the app. The SelectedRow() function is implemented in the line

```
<mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); selectedRow()"
```

So when I check the checkbox in any particular row, the function is called. But the output of the function is ***row number that is selected :*** which means the actual row number is not displayed. The functions that I plan to implement after this will need the row number or some kind of value from the row selected. Can anyone tell me why the row number information isn't retrieved? Below is a screenshot of the table and the output on row selection.

[image]

Comment: where is the `selected` property in the json object? create a stackblitz

Comment: I am not sure how to set that @Aravind, do we need a selected key in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the following code,

```
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

<ng-container matColumnDef="select">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <mat-checkbox (change)="selectAll()"
                      [checked]="allSelected"
                      [indeterminate]="!allSelected && oneSelected">
        </mat-checkbox> 
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <mat-checkbox (change)="change(element)" [checked]="element.selected">
        </mat-checkbox>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Typescript

```
export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
  selected?:boolean
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];

/**
 * @title Basic use of `<table mat-table>`
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['select','position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA
  oneSelected=false;

  allSelected=false;

 change(element:PeriodicElement){
   let e= this.dataSource.find(item=>item.position===element.position);
   if(e){
      e.selected=true;
   }
   this.oneSelected=this.dataSource.filter(item=>item.selected).length>0
 }
 selectAll(){
   if(this.allSelected || !this.oneSelected){
   this.dataSource.forEach(item=>item.selected= false);  
   this.allSelected=true;
   }else{
     this.dataSource.forEach(item=>item.selected= true);
     this.allSelected=false;
     this.oneSelected=false;
   }


 }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e4hkes)